# Prevent SVG from being easily reverse-engineered

Tags: security, image-processing, svg

I just started at a new company and have been asked to do what I believe impossible, but I need confirmation on this. The website that my company has allows users to view images in extremely high resolution using SVGs. We've built a custom viewer for these images that allow you to zoom and scroll around the image and it works well. Because of this, the image format "needs" to remain SVG. However, we need to include a watermark to this image. The way we're doing this right now is passing the SVG and PNG watermark to the client, inserting the watermark into the SVG, and displaying it to the user. This is very obviously easily hacked as anyone with client-side experience knows (The dev team here is mostly older developers and don't have much web experience). Even if the raw SVG isn't intercepted, they can still just delete the watermark from the source. I've convinced my boss to make the watermark be injected on the server-side, so this leaves just the problem that SVGs are editable by the end-client.

What I want to know is if one of these two things are possible:

1) Is there another image format akin to SVG that could be used to keep this highly scalable image without loosing resolution, and without it being directly editable by an end-client? The only options that people seem to discuss for the web is JPG, GIF, PNG, and SVG. I've looked at Adobe Illustrator ".ai" files and EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) as other vector options, but I can't find anywhere if I can modify these images in PHP, which is key if I want to overlay a watermark in server-side code.

2) Is there a way to obfuscate the raw SVGs content so that the use can't go and manipulate it? I've seen SVGs that have `<image ...>` tags inside them with PNGs represented as long and complex strings before. Something like `xlink:href="data:image/png;base64..."`. I was wondering if there's a way to display an SVG as this string, so that the data can't be directly manipulated. I'm sure there's an algorithm to reverse these, but so long as we're sticking with SVGs, I need to make this as secure as possible with as many hoops to jump through as possible if someone wants to steal the data.

Either way would be acceptable, as long as removing this watermark is more complex than just hitting F12 and removing the element inside the dev tools.

Comment: That deserves a few more comments. 1) I'd look at PDF conversion on-the-fly and DRM solutions for PDF. A [link](https://www.locklizard.com/pdf_security_drm/) about that found on Wikipedia, unread. 2) The format is a base64-encoded [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). It can be decoded anytime with the standard Javascript `atob()` command, or by simply copying the string to the browser address field, which will build the open DOM.

Comment: You should probably embed the watermark directly into the image. Like Google maps does.

Comment: I've seen something similar to your viewer done with STL (3D) files. Their solution was simply to obfuscate the client (Javascript) code. I agree with @ccprog. PDF can do this.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there another image format akin to SVG that could be used to keep this highly scalable image without loosing resolution, and without it being directly editable by an end-client?

SVG is a vector format, and to maintain extreme scalability, you need to stick with vectors, be it any format. However, in that case it will always be possible to remove the vectors that belong to your watermark. There are of course vector formats that are stored as binary, which would make it somewhat harder for an enduser to parse and edit, but those are not editable in PHP either, and are much less compatible. So you probably don't want to do this.

#### Is there a way to obfuscate the raw SVGs content so that the user can't go and manipulate it?

First, it will never be "secure" in the sense that as said above, it will always be possible to remove the watermark from a vector image. (Btw the only difference to bitmap formats like JPG is that content below the watermark in bitmap is actually missing, while in SVG it's still there.)

However, depending on how "good" you want this to be, you can do a few things. I think the "goodness" here means the effort needed to remove the watermark, and you can raise the bar relatively easily. You don't have to (and you probably can't reasonably) obfuscate the whole SVG.

One thing that comes to mind is that SVG is basically just XML, it consists of tags like `<rect>`, `<line>`, `<circle>` etc. The order of these tags doesn't matter much (mostly, with exceptions of course). So you could entwine the tags that draw your watermark pretty much randomly among existing tags. I mean really randomly, so different downloads would produce different results. If you do this well (eg. you find line tags to "hide" your watermark line tags, and so on), it will be hard to *automatically* remove the watermark, because it's all over relevant data that is your actual image. Of course, the watermark could still be visually in a corner, and this is already a weakness, anything drawn to a corner could possibly be removed automatically. And it will be easy to remove by hand with any decent editor I suppose. So it depends on what the purpose is.

But I still think this sort of thing could make it hard enough in many scenarios (and would be totally inadequate in others).